# Listbox has different style with mouse and keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I am having problem with listbox style

```
 <ListBox Name="uiList" MaxHeight="300" Width="200">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel ForceCursor="False">
                            <CheckBox Margin="3" Focusable="False" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

 private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!SelectedItems.Contains((sender as CheckBox).DataContext))
        {
            SelectedItems.Add((sender as CheckBox).DataContext);
        }
    }

    private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //If Unchecked CheckBox will remove from SelectedItems
        SelectedItems.Remove((sender as CheckBox).DataContext);
    }
```

[image: this is a screenshoot]

Problem is when select item with mouse and keyboard they have a different style. First two one selected with keyboard others with mouse. Could someone help me with that.
Thank you!

Comment: Where is the style? There is absolute nothing that has color in the codes you provided. Is it done in the two event handlers?

Comment: Anyway, how did the checkbox managed to become checked? It isn't even focusable now.